# Is there any way to read data by bytes length in R

Tags: r, sas, byte, read.fwf

Is there any way to read data by bytes length in R like SAS input command?
When some multi-bytes characters are in a table as fixed column length,

**aaa대전11b1

bb 서울21b2

ccc부산갑b3**

SAS can read it by bytes length as below.

**data test;

infile "filepath";

input

V1      $3.

V2      $6.

V3      $2. ; 

run;**


→

**aaa, 대전11, b1

bb , 서울21, b2

ccc, 부산갑, b3**

But in R, read.fwf only can seperate data by widths not by bytes lengths.

So, command like below

**test <- read.fwf("file path", widths=c(3,6,2))**

outputs error, or at best shape like this

**aaa, 대전11b1, NULL

bb , 서울21b2, NULL

ccc, 부산갑b3**

So, this is my question: Is there any way to seperate data columns by bytes lengths in R?

Comment: checkout this [link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-read-binary-data-into-r/) and see if `readBin()` helps here with little bit of tweaking.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to read the bytes, but the characters. The first two lines have 13 bytes but the third one has 14 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below code you should get the desired output (**note:** you can have this solution as a workaround till the time you find a better way to do it!)

```
file <- readLines("your_data_file.txt",encoding="UTF-8")
newTxt <- unlist(strsplit(file, split = "\u2028"))
newTxt <- lapply(newTxt, function(x) gsub("^([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})$", "\\1,\\2,\\3", x))
df = do.call(rbind.data.frame, newTxt)
names(df) <- "combined_column"

library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(combined_column, c("col1", "col2", "col3"), ",")
```

Output:

```
  col1    col2 col3
1  aaa  대전11   b1
2   bb  서울21   b2
3  ccc  부산갑   b3
```

Comment: @resol if you liked the solution then you should accept it as the right answer. It'll surely help others in case they encounter similar problem in future. Thanks!